# Login no admin do CMS Kooboo com Active directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, cms

Estou em um projeto onde o cliente quer que o login no admin do CMS seja feito através do Active Directory.
O CMS que estamos usando é o Kooboo baseado em aspnet MVC.

Alguém já fez algo parecido? Tem ideia de como faz?

Comment: Você quer mescar os dois tipos de autenticação ou usar somente o AD para isso?

Comment: Aproveitando, o [fórum do Kooboo](http://forum.kooboo.com/yaf_postsm6727_Active-directory-authentication-in-Kooboo.aspx#post6727) possui uma pergunta sobre isso, mas a resposta não é muito animadora.

Comment: Você quer mescar os dois tipos de autenticação ou usar somente o AD para isso?

A ideia principal é usar somente o AD para isso.

Comment: Sim... Eu vi esse tópico no forum do kooboo.
Mas nao ajudou muito.

Comment: Bom, por ter o código aberto, você pode implementar essa *feature* manualmente. O servidor onde será instalado está na mesma rede que o AD ou você contratou uma hospedagem que não é interligada?

Comment: Não está na mesma rede. Mas  eu já estou com as credenciais de acesso ao AD do cliente. Com isso eu criei uma aplicação de teste selecionando como modo de autenticação o AD no Visual Studio e ai o login funcionou normalmente.

Isso, vou ter que pegar o código do Kooboo e dar uma desbravada.
Mas queria saber se alguém já passou por isso.

Comment: A parte de fazer a autenticação deve ser da mesma forma dessa aplicação de teste que você fez. O problema mesmo será alterar os `Attributes` e `Helpers` para tal alteração. Isso impacta muito na parte de permissões do site. [Neste link](http://kooboo.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Kooboo.CMS/Kooboo.CMS.Web/Authorizations/AuthorizeMenuItemInitializer.cs) você consegue ver um pouco como funciona a permissão do Kooboo, que é dividida em Area, Group e Name.

Comment: Mas isso é olhando superficialmente. Para realizar tal alteração é necessário olhar o código mais a fundo e ver os impactos de cada alteração.